# Gitlab backup file location (Omnibus installation)

Tags: backup, git, gitlab

I have installed Gitlab using omnibus installation package.

I took a backup using below command

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create
```

Backup was successfully created. But I am not sure where to find the backup file. Where are all the Gitlab backups are stored by default..?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`/var/opt/gitlab/backups` by default.

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/a64d0f79173301dd86db073e9b6a329b56554dbd/doc/raketasks/backup_restore.md says that:

> This archive will be saved in backup_path (see config/gitlab.yml)

Then https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/9e97671d8dee3ea6a7bbb99347ad279b65689f28/files/gitlab-cookbooks/gitlab/templates/default/gitlab.yml.erb#L208 says it uses the template variable `@backup_path`

And https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/9e97671d8dee3ea6a7bbb99347ad279b65689f28/files/gitlab-cookbooks/gitlab/attributes/default.rb#L120 says:

```
default['gitlab']['gitlab-rails']['backup_path'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/backups"
```

I recommend that you clone GitLab omnibus and `git grep` away for other similar problems, and that you post gitlab questions on SO: it is accepted there and has much greater developer traffic.